# Bluetooth SPP server on Windows

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, bluetooth

I need to write a Windows application that accepts connections over Bluetooth SPP - i.e. other devices can see the SPP service and connect there. Tried googling but not much information available - any examples/meaningful docs/pointers out there?

The OS is Windows 7, using native Bluetooth drivers.

The preferred language is C#, but other ideas are welcome as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32feet.NET seems the obvious choice?  http://32feet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Bluetooth%20Server-side

Speaking as its maintainer... :-,)

Comment: Thanks - gonna give it a try!

Comment: Thanks again, works like a charm for me. Not very reliably, but good enough for our needs so far.

Comment: General wireless unreliability?  Or 32feet.NET code?  Hope the not the latter? :-)

Comment: Im gonna try this. +1

Comment: Coming back after 2 years - http://btframework.com/ is actually a very good choice too (non-free though) - especially if you want a native C++ application. Both approaches work for us like a charm for more than 2 years.